# Order while loop data

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I'm making a ranking system. But what I want is to order the results I get (`$kn`) from highest to lowest. How can I do this?

```
include "includes/core.inc.php";
require "includes/connect.inc.php"; 

$id = $_GET["id"];

$query = "SELECT * FROM submitted WHERE id= '$id'";
$query_run = $db->query($query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)){

    $name= $row["name"];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM submitted WHERE name= '$name' AND pending = 'Accept'";
    $sql_run = $db->query($sql);
    $count = $sql_run->num_rows;

    $nums= "SELECT * FROM ranking WHERE name= '$name'";
    $nums_run = $db->query($nums);
    $num = $nums_run->num_rows;


    $kn = ($count * 0.4) + (($num * 0.2) * 3);

    echo '$name';
    echo '$kn';
}
```

Comment: Which query? `SELECT * FROM ranking WHERE name= '$name' ORDER BY rank DESC`  Assuming there is a column called `rank`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html

Comment: i want to order by the value of $kn

Answer (score 1):

Looping over a list and querying each element is almost never a good idea. Instead, you can move the entire logic to the query, and then sort it there:

```
$query = 
"SELECT   s.name AS name, (cnt_submitted * 0.4) + ((cnt_ranking * 0.2) * 3) AS kn
 FROM     (SELECT   name, COUNT(*) AS cnt_submitted
           FROM     submitted
           WHERE    id = '$id' AND
                    pending = 'Accept'  
           GROUP BY name) s
 JOIN     (SELECT   name, COUNT(*) AS cnt_ranking
           FROM     ranking
           GROUP BY name) r ON r.name = s.name
 ORDER BY 2 DESC";

$query_run = $db->query($query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {

    $name = $row["name"];
    $kn = $row["kn"];

    echo '$name';
    echo '$kn';
}
```

**Note:**
The `$id` variable should probably be a bound variable in a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to safe-guard against SQL-injection attacks.
I left it as it was in the OP, though, since this is not the point of the question and I don't want to add additional confusion.

Comment: This query doesn't make sense(group 1 row)
SELECT   name, COUNT(*) AS cnt_submitted
           FROM     submitted
           WHERE    id = '$id' AND
                    pending = 'Accept' AND  
           GROUP BY name

Comment: @AndrejLudinovskov yipes, had a redundant `and` there. Removed it, thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it also in PHP:

```
$result = [];
while (...) {
    .....

    $kn = ($count * 4) + (($num * 2) * 30);
    $result[] = [
        'rank' => $kn,
        'name' => $name
    ];
}

usort($result, function($a, $b) {
    return $b['rank'] - $a['rank'];
});
```